# difference between initializing an object with these two ways in c#

Tags: c#, class, object

generally i instant `initialize` an `object` when adding it to a `list`
with this way --->

```
list.add(
   new foo() {                       //     <--- foo()
      field1 = value1,
      field2 = value2 
   }
);
```

but once i just tried --->

```
list.add(
   new foo {                     //     <--- foo
      field1 = value1,
      field2 = value2 
   }
);
```

& it worked !!!

in the 2nd way i am just `creating` an `object` without using `()` at tail of it.
so does anyone have any idea about the difference between these various ways to initializing an object ?

Comment: There is an explanation on [Eric Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/20/ambiguous-optional-parentheses.aspx)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> so does anyone have any idea about the difference between these various ways to initializing an object ?

There's no difference at all. In both cases you're using an [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx), and if you don't specify any constructor arguments, that's *exactly* equivalent to providing an empty list of constructor arguments. From section 7.6.10.1 of the C# spec:

> An object creation expression can omit the constructor argument list and enclosing parentheses provided it includes an object initializer or collection initializer. Omitting the constructor argument list and enclosing parentheses is equivalent to specifying an empty argument list.

Note that when you *just* invoke a constructor without using an object initializer (the braces) you *have* to specify the constructor arguments. So:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();    // Valid
Foo foo = new Foo;      // Invalid
Foo foo = new Foo() {}; // Valid
Foo foo = new Foo {};   // Valid
```

The "valid" lines are all exactly equivalent, including any use of default parameters - so `Foo` might only have a constructor like this:

```
// You can invoke this without specifying arguments
public Foo(int x = 0)
{
}
```

See section 7.6.10 of the C# 5 spec for more details.

Comment: but what if Foo doesn't have any constructor like u are saying `Foo(int x = 0)`. bcoz my code is still working without having a constructor

Comment: @AshokDamani: The default value will be applied. It's just syntactic sugar as though you wrote empty parenthesis. With the `x` parameter being an optional parameter, you _could_ call `var f = new Foo()` (which passes in `0`) or `var f = new Foo(){}` (which passes in `0`) or `var f = new Foo { }` (which passes in `0`) or you can explicitly specify it: `var f = new Foo(9999) { }` EDIT: Yeah, sorry about the `struct` question, they specify default constructors always; I overlooked that you declared `x` as an optional parameter.

Comment: @AshokDamani: If you don't supply *any* constructors, then the C# compiler will supply a parameterless one for you, commonly known as a "default constructor".

Answer (score 9):

They are both object initializers. There is no difference. It's a good question though.  I would think that behind the scenes the result is the same.... Compiler creates object with empty constructor and sets properties.

Answer (score 6):

No difference whatsoever. In an object initializer of the *second* form (no parentheses) the parameterless constructor is used by default, but can be specified explicitly. If you want to pass parameters to the constructor you *must* use the first form (with some values, obviously).

Answer (score 3):

As Explained mostly, no difference in both. Whenever we create object always there is default constructor created without any parameter, which initialize members of object with default values(empty/NULL), means your second method will be used. But when we pass parameter at the time of object initialization the constructor must be defined for the the matching definition else it will result in syntax error. If there is no constructor defined for matching definition then there is nothing to pass as values or to initialize object members.